# Weird date time behavior in MS SQL Server Function, different results

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, date, datetime

Having [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/122869) (really awesome) answer, putting that into a function, gave some weird results and I don't understand why, yet I did fix it by simply changing the input parameters to `datetime` instead of `date` for both `@startDate` and `@endDate`. I was looking for an answer, but most problems come with converting dates manually, while this mostly happens automatically (in C#)

So my function looks like this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UnavailableDates]
(
    @ParamProductID int,
    @ParamDays int,
    @ParamStartDate datetime,
    @ParamEndDate datetime
)
RETURNS @unavailableDates TABLE
(
    dt datetime
)
AS
BEGIN 
--...entire refereed answer (second part in the answer), but then targeting real database tables.

INSERT @unavailableDates
SELECT
    dt

FROM CTE_Groups
WHERE
    CASE WHEN AvailableDay = 1 AND GroupSize - GroupRN + 1 >= @ParamDays
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 0
ORDER BY dt;

    RETURN
END
```

So I had three ways of calling this function, one in sql, two in c#:

```sql
DECLARE @ParamProductID int = 120;
DECLARE @ParamDays int = 14;
DECLARE @ParamStartDate datetime = '2016-01-01';
DECLARE @ParamEndDate datetime = '2017-01-01';

SELECT * FROM UnavailableDates(@ParamProductID,@ParamDays,@ParamStartDate,@ParamEndDate);
```

And C#:

```c#
    public static List<DateTime> GetUnavailableDates2(int productId, int days, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseContext"].ConnectionString;
        List<DateTime> returnList = new List<DateTime>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM UnavailableDates(@productId,@days,@startDate,@endDate)", conn);
            SqlParameter productParam = new SqlParameter("@productId", productId);
            SqlParameter daysParam = new SqlParameter("@days", days);
            SqlParameter startDateParam = new SqlParameter("@startDate", startDate);
            SqlParameter endDateParam = new SqlParameter("@endDate", endDate);
            comm.Parameters.Add("@productId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = productId;
            comm.Parameters.Add("@days", SqlDbType.Int).Value = days;
            comm.Parameters.Add("@startDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startDate.Date;
            comm.Parameters.Add("@endDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = endDate.Date;
            SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                returnList.Add(reader.GetDateTime(0));
            }

        }
        //returnList has different (incorrect) results here. After executing the next commands it returns correct results..
        using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext()) //inherits from Entity Framework DbContext
        {
            SqlParameter productParam = new SqlParameter("@productId", productId);
            SqlParameter daysParam = new SqlParameter("@days", days);
            SqlParameter startDateParam = new SqlParameter("@startDate", startDate);
            SqlParameter endDateParam = new SqlParameter("@endDate", endDate);
            SqlParameter[] array = new SqlParameter[4] { productParam, daysParam, startDateParam, endDateParam };
            var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<DateTime>("SELECT * FROM UnavailableDates(@productId,@days,@startDate,@endDate)", array).ToList();

            returnList = result.ToList(); //this now returns the correct results.
        }
        return returnList;
    }
```

So after changing the functions input parameter to `datetime` my second C# example returns the correct results. However, the first C# example returns different results and the normal SQL execution of the function returns different results as well (yet not the same as the first C# example).

As I said, I already fixed the problem, but I am very curious why this happens, and so might be others.

There is no time involved, anywhere, all values that are inserted (via C#) were created without specifying time.

So what is the difference? Very random and to me unpredictable. While the output all start at **2016-01-16** as expected, The SQL version missed date **2016-01-29** till **2016-02-13** and **2016-02-28** till **2016-03-08**. While the C# example missed **2016-02-15** till **2016-02-24**

This might not make sense without test actual data, but what I am trying to say is, that it has a difference of 9 items, not just one or two.

Comment: The method that isn't working is using the class DatabaseContext().  The error is in this class and you didn't post the code for the class.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is Entity Framework DbContext. More precise, it inherits from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` where the called method `db.Database.SqlQuery<DateTime>` is not overwritten. HOWEVER this is the only one that IS returning correct results. The other ones are not.

Comment: I know.  The settings are different , probably the field for DateTim eis set to  a string.  Which means the SQL Server is translating the String to a Time.  Try setting the DbContext Fields to DateTime.

Comment: @RageCompex, just a general advice. Before jumping to the final complex query, make a very simple function, that returns, for example, all dates between `@ParamStartDate` and `@ParamEndDate` plus another `@ParamDays` days. Make sure that it works correctly in SSMS, then in your C# code. Once you confirmed that you found a correct way to run this function from C#, put the real complex query in it. A side note: I'd recommend to use proper types whenever possible, i.e. `date` instead of `datetime`, if it is just a date without time.